# ASP.NET MVC looking for wrong action(without parametrs)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I want to create an edits views, all for one big model in table, but there will be smaller models" for Basic Informations, Contact Informations etc, my model  Table is really big and I don't want to create one edit view with 20 textboxes.

So here is problem I create `HttpGet` Action with parametr id, and `HttpPost` with model. And when I'm sending my form I got error `System.MissingMethodException`, I dont have Action method without parametrs..

`Kontrahenci` is my model from EF for table.
`DaneOglneKontrahenta` is assistant class, to send only 6 variables instead of 20.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EdytujDaneOgolne(int? id)
{

    if (id == null)
    {
        Redirect("Index");
    }

    Kontrahenci kontrahent = db.Kontrahenci.Find(id);

    if (kontrahent == null)
    {
        Redirect("Index");
    }

    DaneOglneKontrahenta model = new DaneOglneKontrahenta(kontrahent);

    return View(model);
}
```

Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EdytujDaneOgolne(int id, DaneOglneKontrahenta kontrahent)
{

    Kontrahenci kontrahentModel = db.Kontrahenci.Find(id);

    if (kontrahentModel == null)
    {
        Redirect("Index");
    }

    kontrahentModel.Nazwa = kontrahent.Nazwa;
    kontrahentModel.NazwaSkrocona = kontrahent.NazwaSkrocona;
    kontrahentModel.NIP = kontrahent.NIP;
    kontrahentModel.Komentarz = kontrahent.Komentarz;
    kontrahentModel.UwagiDS = kontrahent.UwagiDS;
    kontrahentModel.UwagiZlecenie = kontrahent.UwagiZlecenie;

    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("Detalis");
}
```

Then in View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 //Some textboxes 
 <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to specify the controller name and action in the Begin form method

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName",FormMethod.Get)) // Get or Post
{
 //Some textboxes 
 <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Comment: Well i tried it before, without results, but there was one thing that i didnt notice then i got other error. So it works but i notice that i had two errors just now. The second was that i didnt have constructor for model without paramets. Now everything works great

Comment: @Jackob, the default for `Html.BeginForm()` is POST so it should work as long controller and action are in current url. The error you got for not having parameter-less constructor is because when action method runs, first thing it does is trying to create a `DaneOglneKontrahenta` and populate it with the data sent by POST. Internally it does `new DaneOglneKontrahenta()` and crashes since there's no such method.